# Enable/disable Background Execution Limits for all apps

Tags: settings, battery-life, background-process, 8.0-oreo

[Official guide on Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts) (new feature introduced in Android 8 Oreo) has a note:

> Note: By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that target
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher. However, users can enable most
>   of these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if
>   the app targets an API level lower than 26.

I've looked through the Settings on Android 8 emulator and was unable to discover the option mentioned in guide.

Could somebody point me how to enable/disable Background Execution Limits for all apps in Android 8+ Settings?

Answer (score 1):

It's displayed on the "Battery" screen for an app, in the "Manage battery usage" section, but only if the app is a "top [battery] consuming" app.

More info: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/05/24/android-o-background-limitations-not-just-targetsdkversion-o.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that they refers to Background process limit in Developer options. Here we can choose: No background processes